# Identifying cars in drone images

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to identify cars in drone images (like from a quad copter), so I started using opencv's haar classifier. However, it produces a lot of false positives and does not always detect cars correctly. I was thinking a CNN would be better for this job, however I've never done a project like this and I am not sure how to proceed.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import sys

img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1], 1)
print(img)

car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars.xml')

cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 1)
print(len(cars))

for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('img1', img)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

[image: Image 5]

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using something other than opencv, then this solution is viable.

Thankfully Google has come to the rescue and has made a pretty simple and open source solution.

The tensorflow [object detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), makes it really easy to start with object detection. You can use models that google has provided - [detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md), or you can even train your own.

To get started just follow the [installation guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) and you should be good to go, to run the demo!

Then follow the [object detection demo guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) - which should get you detecting many different types of objects - from cars, to people, to dogs and even kites!

Comment: I will check this out, I can definitely use something other than opencv. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to stick with opencv - they recently released a new version, which now includes the `dnn` module.  The sample code for it is here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4/samples/dnn/object_detection.py . Video demo: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d9d/tutorial_dnn_yolo.html

Comment: Opencv, I would think, is more lightweight than tensorflow - so if running on slower hardware maybe use opencv. If accuracy is top priority then I would stick with tensorflow.

Comment: This can be helpful, also the original course by profile Andrew Ng. On Coursera: https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2018/03/11/autonomous-driving-car-detection-with-yolo-in-python/amp/